# Unwanted table cell padding

Tags: html, css, html-table, newsletter

I am creating a newsletter for a client. I am having issues with padding on the topmost td cell on the first inner table. I have no idea why it is creating this extra padding at the bottom of the td. I have tried inline css height, zeroing all padding and margins on it, and I still have not had luck getting rid of the white-space between the two inner tables. I would appreciate any help. It is probably something simple that I am overlooking, but I have run out of ideas.

page with the email template: http://www.bemidjimillworks.com/email_templates/Default-Template.html

The td I am referring to is this one:

```
<td style="width:600px;padding:0;margin:0;">
     <a href="http://www.bemidjimillworks.com">
         <img src="http://www.bemidjimillworks.com/images/newsletter/01_header.jpg" />
     </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Which `<td>` do you mean exactly? What's it content?

Comment: Why you have so many <tables>? I think you could create the same in one <table> and three <tr>s. Any reason?

Comment: @chopper the first <td> that has the 01_header.jpg image in it.

Comment: @user2719346 I am nesting tables, mostly so I don't have to mess with colspan so much. I wouldn't normally do it that way, but since the vertical image thumbnails are right next to a ul, I wasn't sure how to accomplish that without working with divs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the css property **vertical-align: top;** to the top image

```
<img src="http://www.bemidjimillworks.com/images/newsletter/01_header.jpg" style="vertical-align: top;">
```

Comment: Yup, that did it. I probably wouldn't have thought to try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The most widely supported way to vertically align in html email is using the html element `valign="top"`. This is considered best practice in html email design.

CSS `vertical-align` as suggested, [is not fully supported](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) in major email clients (Outlook) and will give you inconsistent results.

Applied to your example:

```
<td valign="top" style="width:600px;padding:0;margin:0;">
     <a href="http://www.bemidjimillworks.com">
         <img src="http://www.bemidjimillworks.com/images/newsletter/01_header.jpg" />
     </a>
</td>
```